# Can spherification be done with hot liquids?

Tags: spherification

Like hot chocolate or something. I realize some liquids are thicker than the other, would it work if its thick and hot?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use konjac flour, but you'll need to raise the pH.  Start with Dutch process cocoa, as regular cocoa is acidic.

From [Guy Crosby](http://www.cookingscienceguy.com/pages/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/A-Molecular-Gastronomer%27s-Dream-Come-True.pdf) (the science guy on America's Test Kitchen):

> But even more surprising, when the pH of a viscous 1% dispersion of konjac flour is raised to pH 9-10.5 by the addition of a mild alkali, then heated to about 85° C (185° F) for 20 minutes, and cooled, the sol transforms into a very firm, but elastic heat-stable gel. So stable that it will not melt even when placed in a 177° C (350° F) pan or oven!